# Definition of improper priors

Tags: bayesian, prior

If a prior integrates to a finite constant that is not 1, is it still considered proper? Is a prior only improper if it integrates to an nonfinite value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classical definition of an *improper prior* in Bayesian statistics is one of a measure $\text{d}\pi$ with infinite mass
$$\int_\Theta \text{d}\pi(\theta)=+\infty$$ See, e.g., [Hartigan's Bayes Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387908838), which formalises quite nicely the use of improper priors. Any measure $\text{d}\pi$ with finite mass can be normalised into a probability measure with mass $1$.

See also this [related Cross validated entry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133711/7224) on improper priors.

Answer (score 6):

Since in the case of $p (\theta) \propto f (\theta) $ with $\int_{\theta \in \Theta} f (\theta) d\theta = c$ integrating to some constant you just need to normalize the density to $f (\theta)/c $, that defines a proper prior.

Comment: That is true, but also note that you do not even need to take care of that as the c cancels out in the integrals when calculating the posterior.