# Why does the MAP differ from the MLE for the uniform prior in Laplace's Rule?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, map-estimation

[Laplace's Rule of Succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession#Mathematical_details) produces an estimate for the probability $p$ of a Bernoulli distribution. It starts with a $Beta(1,1)$ prior (equivalent to a uniform distribution prior on $(0,1)$), and then obtain the Maximum A Posterior (MAP) estimator $\frac{k+1}{n+2}$, where $k$ is the number of success in $n$ trials.

Why does this MAP estimator differ from the MLE estimator of $\frac{k}{n}$ despite having a uniform prior? Especially when it is obvious from the [definition of the MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation#Description) that if the prior distribution $g(p)$ is a constant function, then MLE = MAP.

Attempts:

1. We could say that the $Beta(1,1)$ prior assigns $0$ to the endpoints $p = 0,1$ and hence is not truly uniform/constant. But aren't the endpoints irrelevant for the uniform distribution? The uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ and on $[0,1]$ only differs on a set of measure zero and so should be equivalent?
2. The derivative of the likelihood function in the [derivation of the MLE](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1192/reader/11%20Parameter%20Estimation.pdf) contains $p$ and $1-p$ in the denominator of fractions. Which means the endpoints have to be excluded from the MLE calculations. Why then do we need to include these endpoints for MLE = MAP to hold?
3. In the [definition of the MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation#Description), how do I know what the domain of the prior $g(p)$ should be?

Comment: I do not think your MAP is correct, see my comment to the answer below. What your report is the posterior mean, and the mode (=MAP) of a distribution does not need to coincide with its mean under asymmetry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with a $\operatorname{Beta}(1,1)$ prior, your posterior would be $\operatorname{Beta}(k+1,n-k+1)$.

The mode of a $\operatorname{Beta}(k+1,n-k+1)$ distribution is $\frac{k}{n}$, which is the result you seem to want for an MAP (or MLE) estimator.

But Laplace's rule of succession instead takes the mean of  the $\operatorname{Beta}(k+1,n-k+1)$ distribution, which is $\frac{k+1}{n+2}$.

Personally, I would usually take the mean of the posterior distribution, as the MAP and MLE do not correspond to a loss function and so seem difficult to justify.  I might start with a different prior, such as a Jeffreys' $\operatorname{Beta}(\frac12,\frac12)$ prior.

Comment: (+1) I [repeatedly commented](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/?s=MAP+loss+function) on the discrepancy between using MAP estimators and using a loss based estimator.

Comment: I see where I have gone wrong. I wrongly assumed Laplace's Rule uses the MAP estimator, when it actually uses the mean of the posterior. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

There is [no such thing as an "uninformative" prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information), that brings no information to a model.

For beta-binomial model, with uniform prior $\mathcal{B}(1, 1)$ the *mode* of the posterior (MAP) is $\frac{x+1-1}{x+1+x-n+1-2} = \frac{x}{x+n-x} = \frac{x}{n}$, so it's the same as MLE.

If you want the mean of the posterior to be equal to MLE, there's another prior, though an [improper](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175792/definition-of-improper-priors) one, that leads to the same solution as MLE: it's the [Haldane's prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Haldane%27s_prior_probability_(Beta(0,0))) $\mathcal{B}(0, 0)$.

Comment: Are you sure here? The posterior under a uniform prior is $Beta(k+1,n-k+1)$, and the mode (=MAP) of a beta distribution is, as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference, $(k+1-1)/(k+1+n-k+1-2)=k/n$. Haldane would be a prior under which posterior *mean* and MLE coincide, no?

Comment: @ChristophHanck yep, I misread the question. Fixed.